How to work around VS "can be made static" warning
I am writing a Cpp library in VS2022 community, and for some reason VS gives me a "VCR003 Function can be made static" warning for the exported functions. I am not an export, but it makes absolutely no sense that exported functions will be made with static linkage. What is the right approach here, should I simply suppress these warnings?
Example:
extern "C" {

__declspec(dllexport)
void foo()
{
    // Foo code
}

}



Edit: It turns out this is a bug in VS. For those who encounter the same issue, I am using:


Better to learn the reasoning behind the warning and make an informed decision, I imagine.

I don't think this is a real compiler warning. Insead it's from the additional tools that analyze the code in addition to the compiler.

The shown code does not produce the warning, see https://godbolt.org/z/4zYzxeMfh. Please show a complete [mre].

Seems to be an issue fixed in the next release: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Information-message-VCR003-given-for-ext/10729403?sort=newest&topics=visual+studio+2017

@user17732522 It does on my system. I guess it is related to the issue you mentioned.

@user17732522 Perfect! Thanks for your help.

@user17732522 - I think that would be a good answer.

Since this seems like a bug it would be helpful to post the exact VS version you are running so that later viewers know whether this is their issue also.

@tdelaney I wasn't able to reproduce the warning to begin with. So I am only guessing that this might be the same bug. I can't be sure though. If someone else wants to answer, feel free to use the link.

As the link provided by user17732522:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Information-message-VCR003-given-for-ext/10729403
A fix for this issue has been internally implemented and is being prepared for release.

For me:
the  message occurs when put  the code in cpp file:


The postscript is misleading. A DLL doesn't require that you put the  exported functions in a header. But you have to consider, how are you going to use those exported functions? The common case is that consuming module (EXE or another DLL) is compiled with that header and linked against the export LIB of the first DLL. But this isn't universal. GetProcAddress doesn't require a header file.
